# How to deploy an application to EC2 instances(with Autoscaling) using Jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jboss, devops

I have a Jenkins job and custom-built pipeline already functioning to deploy my Java application using Jboss to an EC2 server in AWS(by using the static IP of the instance). Now I plan to enable the Autoscaling feature for my EC2 instance.

What would be the best practices to make continuous deployments to these scaled EC2 instances maintaining the application's stability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the workflow I follow using Jenkins.

- Create a [Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) that does a build and pushes to Amazon S3 - In an artifact bucket
- Create a [CodeDeploy application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html) that deploys to the autoscaling group (not tag)
- Create a [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) application that polls for the S3 object, and when receved triggers CodeDeploy.

The great thing about CodeDeploy when attached to autoscaling groups is it creates a [lifecycle hook](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/). Whenever a new instance is deployed to the autoscaling group it will automatically deploy the latest version of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aws cli to know the public/Private ip by using the grep and awk command and then you can store ip address in a file and at a time of deployment you can use that file to deploy so when ever autoscaling create a machine you have IP where you want to deployed use that file and deployment is done

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35042229)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).